# What happened to Pixie in the mines of Abergylid?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In the Free Comic Book Day 2008 issue "Pixies and Demons", the X-Men head into the mines of Abergylid chasing demons. On their way down on a lift, Emma Frost telepathically says to Pixie, "I can feel how *afraid* you are of this place. And *why*. Do you want me to *remove* that fear?" Pixie replies, "No, thank you. There's--too much else *attached* to it."

What is Pixie referring to - what significance do the mines hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixie's father was a miner who died in those mines. It later turns out that her father was imitated by Mastermind. I don't know (and can't find) how much of her memories of her father *are* her father. So anything she can remember is precious to her.